# How can I add a new CSS class to a widget?

Tags: widgets

I want to assign a new CSS class to default widget `<ul>` in Page/Post creating page in WordPress. How can I do this?

See the image below.

[image]

Comment: It can be declared when creating the sidebar widget holder.
[I think this has been answered here.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16885510/3252930

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't edit your parent theme's `functions.php` file.

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'Sidebar name', 'theme_text_domain' ),
    'id'            => 'unique-sidebar-id',
    'description'   => '',
    'class'         => 'add class here',
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</li>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>'
) );
```

Copy it over to your child theme's `functions.php` and make the changes there, or simply register a new widget.

You could then hook it in from your child theme's `functions.php` like this:

```
add_action( 'your_hook', 'new_widget' );
function new_widget() {
    if ( is_your_conditional_tag() && is_active_sidebar( 'new-widget' ) ) { 
        dynamic_sidebar( 'new-widget', array(       
            'before' => '<div class="new-widget">',
            'after' => '</div>'
        ) );
    }
}
```

You can also add more classes to the [dynamic_sidebar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar) function.

Comment: This doesn't work. The class gets added in the admin interface, not on the frontend.

Comment: Make sure you swap out your_hook with a theme specific or WordPress hook and also swap out the conditional tag with a working conditional tag,

Answer (score 2):

Go to your `function.php` and find your widget code

You must add or edit that `class` parameters in your sidebar code like that  `'class'       => 'new-class',`

It would be like that:

```
register_sidebar(array(
  'name' => __( 'Right Hand Sidebar' ),
  'id' => 'right-sidebar',
  'class'       => 'new-class',
  'description' => __( 'Widgets in this area will be shown on the right-hand side.' ),
  'before_title' => '<h1>',
  'after_title' => '</h1>'
));
```

You must check out [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) for more usage

Answer (score 0):

you had written wrong question. its not on widget but on post/page description.

AS per codex you needs to add extra styles to css file. you can add class via code but this is better solution. see this [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/User:Lorelle/Customizing_The_Content) link for details

### Styling Lists

```
#content ul {margin: 0.3em 1em; list-style-position: outside; list-style:url(ball.gif) disc; font-size:98%}
#content ul ul {margin-top: 0.3em; list-style:url(bullet.gif) square; font-size:96%}
#content ul ul ul {margin-top: 0.3em; list-style:url(ball1.gif) circle; font-size:98%}
#content li, #content li li, #content li li li {padding:0.25px 10px 5px 0.25em}
```